# How to remove the separator from a table view Controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am working on code where I want to remove the separators from `UITableViewController`. I am able to do that using a normal `viewcontroller` and adding a table view to it, but not while I am using a `UITableViewController`. The interface `Builder` doesn't change the separator value.

Comment: How about [self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; in viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 3):

If You remove Separator from Xid , plz see the Image ,and use
[image]

and Clean the Background

[image]

if you want change from code , then use

```
self.tblview.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove it coding

```
self.tableview.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

or choose tableview in xib and change separator style

Comment: I am not able to change separator style in xib. The statement also doesnt work. Maybe this is because this is bydefault a table view controller and therefore in xib, we are not able to tamper with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

or else

in **Xib** in **tableview** properties select **NONE** in **STYLE** property.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using this in `viewDidLoad.` And it works for me.

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

If it is not working for you, can you check if you have created your `UITableViewControler` in Xib properly.